# How to properly use Laravel Heroku & Deploybot?

Tags: php, heroku, deployment, laravel-5.1

So during my learning phase of Laravel, i've found many interesting subjects, but this question has not been answered before. i have done my research, and would like someone to help perform this task, and save time. Instead of buying into forge, i feel deploybot is the free option, for a poor man like me.

Here are the steps i've used to deploy the app. I am getting the following errors.

```
1. Loading laravel app on phpstorm.
2. Adding git to bitbucket.
3. Configuring bitbucket in deploybot and adding heroku as host.
4. Loading all the files on heroku using the following commands. 

heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php

5. Adding Procfile 'web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/'
```

Here is the error im receiving.

```
Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

Comment: in your .env file set APP_DEBUG to true, in order to get more details about the error. And of course, if is possible, try to attach any messages here from log's file, it would be useful.

Comment: I think i've nailed the problem. I need to add buildpack before deployment. But deploybot doesn't allow bash commands before deployment.

Comment: Heroku allows you to trigger commands via composer. So, you can edit your composer.json file and add the comman there. It is an option I guess.

Comment: I get it, but "heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php", needs to go before composer.json is uploaded. Heroku is taking that dyno as simple node application.